# Suppose that the number of accidents X in a factory is distributed as Poisson $X|\theta \sim Poisson(\theta)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian

Suppose that the number of accidents $X$ in a factory is distributed as Poisson $X|\theta \sim Poisson(\theta)$. Assume the a priori distribution
$$
f(\theta) = \frac{3^4\theta^{4-1}e^{-3\theta}}{\Gamma(4)}, \theta \geq 0
$$
Given $18$ accidents in the first $6$ months, obtain the posterior distribution of $\theta$ and calculate its mean and variance.

My attempt: If $X|\theta \sim Poisson(\theta)$, then $f(x, \theta)=\frac{e^{-\theta} \theta ^x}{x!}$ for $x = {0, 1, 2, ...}$ and $\theta >0$. Then the posterior distribution function is given by
$$
f(\theta | x)  \propto f(x|\theta)f(\theta) = \left(e^{-\theta}\theta ^{x}\right)\left(\theta ^{4-1}e^{-3\theta}\right)= e^{-4\theta}\theta ^{x+3} 
$$
Hence, $\theta|X$ is proportional to $\Gamma(x+4,4)$. Now how can I use the information about the $18$ accidents in the first $6$ months to obtain the mean and the variance of the posterior distribution?

Comment: Is there some missing detail in the definition of $X$? Is $X$ the number of accidents per month, or per 6 months?

Comment: I'm not sure, the statement doesn't mention it.

Comment: Assuming $X$ is the number of accidents in 6 months, I think you essentially plug in $x=18$ to obtain that the posterior is $\Gamma(18+4, 4)$. Then find the mean and variance of this distribution.

Comment: If $X$ is the numbers of accidents per month, then it'd be $\Gamma(3+4, 4)$, right?